# Gatsby and react-intl - How to make current language key available as global context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a Gatsby website that is using react-intl.  I am successfully able to switch languages.  Currently the `<IntlProvider>` is defined in layout.js, like so:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query LayoutQuery {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              languages {
                defaultLangKey
                langs
              }      
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={data => {
        const url = globalHistory.location.pathname;
        const { langs, defaultLangKey } = data.site.siteMetadata.languages;
        const langKey = getCurrentLangKey(langs, defaultLangKey, url);
        const homeLink = `/${langKey}/`;
        const langsMenu = getLangs(langs, langKey, getUrlForLang(homeLink, url))
        let showLanguageSelect = true;
        let onHomePage = true;
        showLanguageSelect = url === '/404/' ? showLanguageSelect = false : showLanguageSelect = true;
        onHomePage = url === '/en/' || url === '/fr/' ? onHomePage = true : onHomePage = false;
        return (
          <IntlProvider
            locale={langKey}
            messages={i18nMessages[langKey]}
          >
            <div>
              <Header langs={langsMenu} homeLink={homeLink} showLanguageSelect={showLanguageSelect} homeHeader={onHomePage} />
              <div>
                {children}
              </div>
              {showLanguageSelect && <Footer langs={langsMenu} homeLink={homeLink}/>}
            </div>
          </IntlProvider>
        )
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

However this provider doesn't pass props to all children in the same way React context would.  Trying to use the following code from a component I don't explicitly pass the langKey to results in an error:

```
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';

const MyComponent: FC = () => {
    const intl = useIntl()
    return <div>{`Current locale: ${intl.locale}`}</div>
}

export default MyComponent
```

"[React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object.  needs to exist in the component ancestry."

Ideally I'd like to have langKey available as global context.  How could I do this?